# Trying to display the two dimmensional array contents in java

Tags: java

I'm a new to java.I'm looking to print the contents in the two dimmensional array namely myPoints.However,when i'm printing the code.it is throwing up the following error.

```
 mypoints4
 i value is 0
 2
 i value is 1
 5
 i value is 2
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:                             
  2 at perceptron.main(perceptron.java:37)



 import java.util.*;
 import java.io.*;
 import java.text.*;
 import java.math.*;
 import java.awt.*;
 class perceptron{

   public static void main(String[] args){
     int[][] myPoints = {{2,3},{4,5},{7,8},{9,10}};
     int [][] myplot  = {{3,4},{5,6},{5,5},{5,3}};
     int sum=0;
     int i=0;
     System.out.println("mypoints"+myPoints.length);
     while(i<=myPoints.length){
       System.out.println("i value is"+i);
       System.out.println(myPoints[i][i]);
       i = i+1;
     }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use nested loops for that.
The reason you get the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is because you're using `myPoints[i][i]`, so when `i` is 2 it is looking for the third element of the third inner array (ie `{7,8}`) when it doesn't exist

Answer (score 1):

This is because of `while(i<=myPoints.length)` need to be `while(i<myPoints.length)`.. In case of array in size 5, your i should be i=0, i=1, i=2, i=3, i=4.. Exclude 5.

Another issue is:

```
System.out.println(myPoints[i][i]);
```

should be : `System.out.println(myPoints[i][0] + " " + myPoints[i][1]);`

Because the second dimensional of youre array is only 2 size.. and not 5

Answer (score 0):

Your condition on the while loop must be "less" not "less or equal". 
This is because the array index is zero based and hence the index range is always from 0 to (length - 1).

Answer (score 0):

1. You're going up to (and *including*) the length of the outer array. This is an array index out of bounds because the indices of an array of length `n` are `0 ... (n-1)`. So trying to access index `n` is out of bounds.
2. You're accessing the sub array at index `i`, which is out of bounds for later sub arrays. This would work for a square matrix (you'd read down the diagonal), but your matrix is 4*2, so `myPoints[2][2]` is OOB, because you can't access index `2` of the length `2` array `{7,8}`.

The simplest way to iterate over every element in a 2-D array is to have to have a *nested* loop, like such:

```
for(int i = 0; i < myPoints.length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < myPoints[i].length; j++){
        System.out.println(myPoints[i][j]);
    }
}
```

An even more concise way of doing this is by using a *for-each* loop, which gets rid of indices entirely and just gives you each element in the array, in order:

```
for(int[] row : myPoints){
    for(int val : row){
        System.out.println(val);
    }
}
```

An *even* more concise way is to use the method [Arrays.deepToString(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString(java.lang.Object[])):

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(myPoints));
```